# Replacing DIV content using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've trawled the site and am struggling to find a solid answer to my query... Basically I have these controls;

```
<div id="prod1">
<div id="prod" class="green">
<div id="prodImg"><img src="images/prod_1_image.png" width="200" height="137" alt=""></div>
<div id="prodRating"><img src="images/prod_1_rating.png" width="200" height="14" alt=""></div>
<div id="prodInfo"><p>Brand/range name praesent eg odio arcu praesent eg odio arcu praesent eg odio arcu.</p></div>
<div id="prodPricing"><p>£99.99* <span class="was">was £229.99</span></p></div>
<div id="prodSaving"><p>Save over £150.00</p></div>
<div id="prodOffering"><p>+ Free delivery</p></div>
<div id="prodColour">
<div class="select"><a href="#" id="green"></a></div>
<div><a href="#" id="mauve" class="mauve1"></a></div>
<div><a href="#" id="brown" class="brown1"></a></div>
<div><a href="#" id="grey" class="grey1"></a></div>
<div><a href="#" id="white" class="white1"></a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The controls re-occur throughout the script which is outlined below;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".green1").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var content = $(this).html();
$('#prod1').html('<div id="prod" class="green"><div id="prodImg"><img src="images/prod_1_image.png" width="200" height="137" alt=""></div><div id="prodRating"><img src="images/prod_1_rating.png" width="200" height="14" alt=""></div><div id="prodInfo"><p>Brand/range name praesent eg odio arcu praesent eg odio arcu praesent eg odio arcu.</p></div><div id="prodPricing"><p>£99.99* <span class="was">was £229.99</span></p></div><div id="prodSaving"><p>Save over £150.00</p></div><div id="prodOffering"><p>+ Free delivery</p></div><div id="prodColour"><div class="select"><a href="#" id="green"></a></div><div><a href="#" id="mauve" class="mauve1"></a></div><div><a href="#" id="brown" class="brown1"></a></div><div><a href="#" id="grey" class="grey1"></a></div><div><a href="#" id="white" class="white1"></a></div></div><div id="prodCompare"><input name="Compare" type="checkbox" value="Compare"><p> Compare</p></div></div>');
});

$(".mauve1").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var content = $(this).html();
$('#prod1').html('<div id="prod" class="mauve"><div id="prodImg"><img src="images/prod_2_image.png" width="200" height="137" alt=""></div><div id="prodRating"><img src="images/prod_1_rating.png" width="200" height="14" alt=""></div><div id="prodInfo"><p>Brand/range name praesent eg odio arcu praesent eg odio arcu praesent eg odio arcu.</p></div><div id="prodPricing"><p>£99.99* <span class="was">was £229.99</span></p></div><div id="prodSaving"><p>Save over £150.00</p></div><div id="prodOffering"><p>+ Free delivery</p></div><div id="prodColour"><div><a href="#" id="green" class="green1"></a></div><div class="select"><a href="#" id="mauve"></a></div><div><a href="#" id="brown" class="brown1"></a></div><div><a href="#" id="grey" class="grey1"></a></div><div><a href="#" id="white" class="white1"></a></div></div><div id="prodCompare"><input name="Compare" type="checkbox" value="Compare"><p> Compare</p></div></div>');
});

$(".brown1").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var content = $(this).html();
$('#prod1').html('<div id="prod" class="brown"><div id="prodImg"><img src="images/prod_3_image.png" width="200" height="137" alt=""></div><div id="prodRating"><img src="images/prod_1_rating.png" width="200" height="14" alt=""></div><div id="prodInfo"><p>Brand/range name praesent eg odio arcu praesent eg odio arcu praesent eg odio arcu.</p></div><div id="prodPricing"><p>£99.99* <span class="was">was £229.99</span></p></div><div id="prodSaving"><p>Save over £150.00</p></div><div id="prodOffering"><p>+ Free delivery</p></div><div id="prodColour"><div><a href="#" id="green" class="green1"></a></div><div><a href="#" id="mauve" class="mauve1"></a></div><div class="select"><a href="#" id="brown"></a></div><div><a href="#" id="grey" class="grey1"></a></div><div><a href="#" id="white" class="white1"></a></div></div><div id="prodCompare"><input name="Compare" type="checkbox" value="Compare"><p> Compare</p></div></div>');
});

$(".grey1").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var content = $(this).html();
$('#prod1').html('<div id="prod" class="grey"><div id="prodImg"><img src="images/prod_1_image.png" width="200" height="137" alt=""></div><div id="prodRating"><img src="images/prod_1_rating.png" width="200" height="14" alt=""></div><div id="prodInfo"><p>Brand/range name praesent eg odio arcu praesent eg odio arcu praesent eg odio arcu.</p></div><div id="prodPricing"><p>£99.99* <span class="was">was £229.99</span></p></div><div id="prodSaving"><p>Save over £150.00</p></div><div id="prodOffering"><p>+ Free delivery</p></div><div id="prodColour"><div><a href="#" id="green" class="green1"></a></div><div><a href="#" id="mauve" class="mauve1"></a></div><div><a href="#" id="brown" class="brown1"></a></div><div class="select"><a href="#" id="grey"></a></div><div><a href="#" id="white" class="white1"></a></div></div><div id="prodCompare"><input name="Compare" type="checkbox" value="Compare"><p> Compare</p></div></div>');
});

$(".white1").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var content = $(this).html();
$('#prod1').html('<div id="prod" class="white"><div id="prodImg"><img src="images/prod_2_image.png" width="200" height="137" alt=""></div><div id="prodRating"><img src="images/prod_1_rating.png" width="200" height="14" alt=""></div><div id="prodInfo"><p>Brand/range name praesent eg odio arcu praesent eg odio arcu praesent eg odio arcu.</p></div><div id="prodPricing"><p>£99.99* <span class="was">was £229.99</span></p></div><div id="prodSaving"><p>Save over £150.00</p></div><div id="prodOffering"><p>+ Free delivery</p></div><div id="prodColour"><div><a href="#" id="green" class="green1"></a></div><div><a href="#" id="mauve" class="mauve1"></a></div><div><a href="#" id="brown" class="brown1"></a></div><div><a href="#" id="grey" class="grey1></a></div><div class="select"><a href="#" id="white"></a></div></div><div id="prodCompare"><input name="Compare" type="checkbox" value="Compare"><p> Compare</p></div></div>');
});
});
</script>
```

The point of the script is to change a DIV based on your colour selection. So say i have a range of cars and wanted the customer to pick a colour I can get my script to work once, but then after that it doesn't work again.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, as I am really struggling :/

Comment: Its because you would need to use the .on method to implement it the way youre trying to now.  But thats not even necessary.  You should should set up some classes that you can add an remove to one div rather than replacing dom content every time.

Comment: yes, the .on method is needed to handle events assigned to dynamically inserted content, however, I think you might like my answer below as a better solution overall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't change your div, just create all of them and then hide and show them as needed.

```
<div id="products">
    <div id="prod1" class="prod green">
        <div id="prodImg"><img src="images/prod_1_image.png" width="200" height="137" alt=""></div>
        <div id="prodRating"><img src="images/prod_1_rating.png" width="200" height="14" alt=""></div>
            <div id="prodInfo"><p>This is Green</p><p>Brand/range name praesent eg odio arcu praesent eg odio arcu praesent eg odio arcu.</p></div>
        <div id="prodPricing"><p>£99.99* <span class="was">was £229.99</span></p></div>
        <div id="prodSaving"><p>Save over £150.00</p></div>
        <div id="prodOffering"><p>+ Free delivery</p></div>
    </div>
    <div id="prod2" class="prod mauve">
        <div id="prodImg"><img src="images/prod_2_image.png" width="200" height="137" alt=""></div>
        <div id="prodRating"><img src="images/prod_1_rating.png" width="200" height="14" alt=""></div>
            <div id="prodInfo"><p>This is Mauve</p><p>Brand/range name praesent eg odio arcu praesent eg odio arcu praesent eg odio arcu.</p></div>
        <div id="prodPricing"><p>£99.99* <span class="was">was £229.99</span></p></div><div id="prodSaving"><p>Save over £150.00</p></div>
        <div id="prodOffering"><p>+ Free delivery</p></div>
    </div>
    <div id="prod3" class="prod brown">
        <div id="prodImg"><img src="images/prod_2_image.png" width="200" height="137" alt=""></div>
        <div id="prodRating"><img src="images/prod_1_rating.png" width="200" height="14" alt=""></div>
            <div id="prodInfo"><p>This is Brown</p><p>Brand/range name praesent eg odio arcu praesent eg odio arcu praesent eg odio arcu.</p></div>
        <div id="prodPricing"><p>£99.99* <span class="was">was £229.99</span></p></div><div id="prodSaving"><p>Save over £150.00</p></div>
        <div id="prodOffering"><p>+ Free delivery</p></div>
    </div>
    <div id="prod4" class="prod grey">
        <div id="prodImg"><img src="images/prod_2_image.png" width="200" height="137" alt=""></div>
        <div id="prodRating"><img src="images/prod_1_rating.png" width="200" height="14" alt=""></div>
            <div id="prodInfo"><p>This is Grey</p><p>Brand/range name praesent eg odio arcu praesent eg odio arcu praesent eg odio arcu.</p></div>
        <div id="prodPricing"><p>£99.99* <span class="was">was £229.99</span></p></div><div id="prodSaving"><p>Save over £150.00</p></div>
        <div id="prodOffering"><p>+ Free delivery</p></div>
    </div>
    <div id="prod5" class="prod white">
        <div id="prodImg"><img src="images/prod_2_image.png" width="200" height="137" alt=""></div>
        <div id="prodRating"><img src="images/prod_1_rating.png" width="200" height="14" alt=""></div>
            <div id="prodInfo"><p>This is White</p><p>Brand/range name praesent eg odio arcu praesent eg odio arcu praesent eg odio arcu.</p></div>
        <div id="prodPricing"><p>£99.99* <span class="was">was £229.99</span></p></div><div id="prodSaving"><p>Save over £150.00</p></div>
        <div id="prodOffering"><p>+ Free delivery</p></div>
    </div>            
</div>
<div id="prodColour">
   <div class="select">
      <div><a href="#" id="green">Show Green</a></div>
      <div><a href="#" id="mauve" class="mauve">Show Mauve</a></div>
      <div><a href="#" id="brown" class="brown">Show Brown</a></div>
      <div><a href="#" id="grey" class="grey">Show Grey</a></div>
      <div><a href="#" id="white" class="white">Show White</a></div>
   </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#prod1").show();
    $("#prodColour .select").on("click", "a", (function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $(".prod").hide();
       $(".prod." + $(this).attr("id")).show();
    }));
});
```

Comment: I like iGanja's response, but all it did was hide the initial image. I think it is the way to pursue this issue, i just can't see what's wrong :/

Comment: Hi @takuhii, I edited the answer for you and created a working fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/iGanja/vRRpa/1/

Comment: @takuhii If this works for you, would you please vote up and mark as the answer. This took me some time; thanks.

Comment: Awesome, I can see where I went wrong too, thank you ever so much :)

I don't have enough points to vote things up, but I have marked it as THE answer and you have my gratitude :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it isn't working more than the first time is that although the class changes, the event binding doesn't, so even if the class is updated to ".grey1," the jQuery code wont know to look for it because it didn't exist when $(document).ready was called (when your page initially loaded). Livequery will help out a lot in this case by dynamically updating your event binding.

Change

```
$(".grey1").click(function(e){
  // Stuff
});
```

To

```
$(".grey1").livequery(function() {
  $(this).click(function(e) {
    // Stuff
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".green1, .white1, .mauve1 /*etc*/ ").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var newClass = $(this).getClass().substring(0, $(this).getClass().length-1);
  $('#prod').addClass(newclass);
});
```

But I would probably use the data attribute or refactor my classes a bit so I was not dependent on substringing the classname to remove the 1